# Is it possible to travel across to the next slide from a current slide?

Tags: reveal.js

The following almost works for me.  But I am having trouble figuring out how to travel horizontally across from any given slide. Based on the following how do I get from **va slide 2** to **vb slide 2** in one click?  Is my HTML setup wrong for that process?

```
<div class="reveal">
        <div class="slides">

            <section data-transition="zoom">
                <section data-transition="slide">va slide 1</section>
                <section data-transition="slide">va slide 2</section>
                <section data-transition="slide">va slide 3</section>
            </section>

            <section data-transition="zoom">
                <section>vb slide 1</section>
                <section>vb slide 2</section>
                <section>vb slide 3</section>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.  All I needed to do was add an additional JavaScript component to customize my directional flow.  There are options for controlling the navigation component in Reveal.js with **navigationMode**.  You can configure your slide direction in 3 flavors [**default** | **linear** | **grid**].  I was looking for grid.

More on that here in the [docs](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#navigation-mode).

and a sample of where to put it would look like this:

```
Reveal.initialize({
            controls: true,
            controlsTutorial: true,
            progress: false,
            history: true,
            transition: 'slide', //none|false|slide|convex|zoom
            navigationMode: 'grid',
  ...
  });
```